# Vagrant complains host path is missing

Tags: vagrant

I want to sync the host's Gradle user home with the guest's, so I'm using this Vagrant config:

```
  config.vm.synced_folder `./gradlew -q gradleHome`, "/home/vagrant/.gradle"
```

I've built a Gradle task to print Gradle user home. When I just run this task, it works fine:

```
C:\Users\chris\work\myproject>gradlew -q gradleHome
C:\Users\chris\.gradle
```

But when I try to "vagrant up", it complains:

```
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: C:/Users/chris/.gradle
```

Note the use of forward vs. backslashes. The directory does exist.

Comment: if you run from windows, can you add `type: "smb"` like `  config.vm.synced_folder `./gradlew -q gradleHome`, "/home/vagrant/.gradle", type: "smb"`

Comment: Thanks, but making it an SMB share doesn't help. I don't see why it would, either; there are other shares working fine with this Vagrantfile. And using SMB would make it unusable for my non-Windows using co-workers, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would probably need to have your gradle command to resolve as C:\Users\chris\.gradle or C:/Users/chris/.gradle

you can try to replace in your Vagrantfile and hardcode with the 3 following values:

```
1. C:\\Users\\chris\\.gradle
2. C:/Users/chris/.gradle
3. C:\Users\chris\.gradle
```

only the first 2 should work, the 3rd will return an error.

clearly `smb`is reserved for windows users only so if you share with others it would not work, but I thought as it is reserved for windows, the resolution of the path would be more tolerant.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Using those literal strings worked, which was the clue that something else was going on. There was a newline hidden in the path.

Answer (score 0):

There was a newline in the string returned by running Gradle. This line in my Vagrantfile does the trick:

```
config.vm.synced_folder `./gradlew -q gradleUserHome`.strip, "/home/vagrant/.gradle"
```

(I added .strip to the command.)